# ocaml function applied too many arguments

Tags: ocaml

i try the below code to do a recursive from i -> 0 and output white space

```
let print_tab fmt i = 
    match i with
    | 0 -> put fmt "%s" "" 
    | _ -> put fmt "%s" "    " ; print_tab fmt (i-1)
```

however it does not work, show the error like below

```
 Error: This function is applied to too many arguments;
 maybe you forgot a `;'
```

i have try another code

```
let print_tab fmt = function
    | 0 -> put fmt "%s" "" 
    | j -> put fmt "%s" "    " ; print_tab fmt (j-1)
```

but it get the same error, what's wrong?

Comment: do i need to declare i = ref?

Comment: What is the function `put`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that you forgot `rec` so your function is not recursive and tries to use a previously defined version of `print_tab`.